# Crystal build fails with "ld: library not found for -lssl"

Tags: macos, crystal-lang, kemal

I've just started a brand new Crystal app, added Kemal, and when building the "Hello World!" app from the Kemal documentation, I get:

`$ crystal build --release src/orderprinterlinks.cr
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

On OSX 10.12.4

Any ideas why the library is not being found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIXED! Error was unrelated to Crystal / Kemal.. running the below command fixes the issue:

`xcode-select --install`

Seems the XCode CLI tools are removed silently when upgrading XCode versions, so this adds them back in, then everything works!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ xcode-select --install
$ xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```